# How to use ng-animate to add slide effect on menu

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to implement a slide effect using ng-animate and CSS styles, but can't figure out what's wrong with my code...

Can I do this using values in percentages for `min-height` and `max-height`? I cant use fixed values in px.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ku6w2vvs/11/)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <a href="#" class="toggle-menu" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">Click to toggle menu</a>
  <div class="menu" ng-show="collapsed" ng-animate="{show: 'menu-show', hide: 'menu-hide'}">
    <div class="files">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label>first</label>

      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label>second</label>
    </div>
    <div class="diffs">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label>first</label>

      <input type="checkbox" />
      <label>second</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu-show-setup, .menu-hide-setup {
  transition:all 0.5s ease-out;
  overflow:hidden
}

.menu-show-setup {
  max-height:0;
}
.menu-show-setup.menu-show-start {
  max-height:25%;
}

.menu-hide-setup {
  max-height:25%;
}
.menu-hide-setup.menu-hide-start {
  max-height:0;
}
```

Comment: Could you be more descriptive when describing the actual error that you encounter? Could you post any errors that you see when using a debugger?

Comment: My issue is that the slide effect doesn't work. There are no errors in debugger.

Comment: Check this question I posted regarding ng-animate, it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33927043/4515720

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't define ng-animate as a dependency, therefore it is not used. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

Comment: @S.B. to be fair, his fiddle doesn't contain any angular code, at all.

Comment: @EvanBechtol It does initialize an (anonymous) ng-app in the most outer div, which is why the toggle works at all.

Comment: @S.B. true, I think that it would be helpful of O.P. to update the post with the app.js file that shows application dependencies.

Comment: I have updated my fiddle. I don't have experience using AngularJS and some answers with code would help me a lot...

Comment: @PavelValeriuthe link I sent would help you quite a bit, it literally contains your answer

Comment: refer this SO answer to understand how `ng-animate` works, http://stackoverflow.com/a/15863113/1677272

Answer (score 0):

First ensure you have angular and angular-animate loaded.
The CDN for angular-animate is ...

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-animate.js"></script>
```

Then you need to reference the animations that ngAnimate gives ...

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate

For example, ng-if when switched from false to true will add the class .fade AND .ng-enter to the element on which the ng-if is located. These classes will be automatically removed after a short time. ngAnimate does this for you.

What you HAVE to do is to style what these classes do ...

example:

```
.fade.ng-enter {
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:0;
}

/* The finishing CSS styles for the enter animation */
.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}
```

now ng-animate will animate from .fade.ng-enter to .fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active

if you do not define these styles ng-animate will do nothing.
You will see classes being added and remove by ng-animate if you inspect the relevant element in your browser's develop tools. If you cannot see these classes being added and removed then something is wrong with your loading of angular or ng-animate.

Comment: Tried all kind of solutions but none of them work...this bring me headaches. What is wrong with this code? https://jsfiddle.net/wad7rzLa/4/